# The function $\phi(p)=\|f\|_{L^p}^p$ is convex

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

> Fix an arbitrary function $f\in L^p([0,1])$ and define
>   $$\phi(p)=\|f\|_{L^p}^p$$ for $p\in [1,\infty)$. Prove $\phi$ is
>   convex.

Comments: This is a standard property of $L^p$ spaces, but no good reference is available online. This question aims to fix that.

Comment: @Calculon We are then finished if we use the fact that the composition of (nondecreasing) convex functions is convex.

Comment: @Calculon The non-decreasing hypothesis is essential. You are right that without that hypothesis, the claim is not true in general.

Comment: I just realized that I misread the question. $f$ is fixed in the question. I thought $p$ was fixed.. My apologies.

Answer (score 6):

You have
$$ \phi(p) = \int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert^p \, dx $$
$p \mapsto x^p = e^{p\log{x}}$ is smooth for $x \geqslant 0$, so we can differentiate twice with respect to $p$,
$$ \phi''(p) = \int_0^1 \lvert f(x) \rvert^p (\log{\lvert f(x) \rvert})^2 \, dx, $$
which is obviously nonnegative. (This is consistent even for $f$ possessing zeros if we make the standard definition $0\log{0}=0$.)

---

Had to think about this one for a while, but the reason that the integral exists is that $|f|^p (\log{|f|})^2 \in L^{p+\varepsilon}[0,1] $ for any $\varepsilon>0$, so you can show the second derivative is exists and is positive on an open interval $(p_1,p_2)$ provided $ f \in L^{p_2} $, which is sufficient for convexity.

Comment: How do we show that the second integral converges? This is not obvious to me.

Comment: In order for differentiation under the integral sign to be permissible, you need an integrable dominating function for the derivative, I believe.

Comment: @Potato I eventually worked out what was going on with the existence, so I've edited my answer.

Comment: Could you explain why $|f|^p(\log |f|)^2\in L^{p+\epsilon}$?

Comment: Obviously we only have to check the behaviour of $ x^{p+\varepsilon} (\log{x} )^2 $ as $x \to 0$ and $ x \to \infty $. Use that $\log{x} = o(x^{\varepsilon})$ as $x \to \infty$, and $\log{x}=o(x^{-\varepsilon})$ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Remarks:** The argument below proves the following.

> Let $1<r<\infty$ and $f\in L^r(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ for some probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$. Then, the function $\phi:[1,r]\to$$\mathbb R$ defined by $\phi(p)=\|f\|^{p}_{L^p}$ is convex.

---

Choose $\theta\in[0,1]$ and $p,q\in[1,r]$. Then, $\theta p+(1-\theta)q\in[1,r]$. Note that, by the monotonicity of the $L^p$-norm, since $f\in L^{r}$ then $f\in L^p, L^{\theta p+(1-\theta)q}\text{ and }L^q$. Moreover, by the [arithmetic-mean/geometric-mean inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means),
$$
\phi(\theta p+(1-\theta)q)=\|f\|_{L^{\theta p+(1-\theta)q}}^{\theta p+(1-\theta)q}=\int_{\Omega}|f|^{\theta p+(1-\theta)q}d\mu=\int_{\Omega}|f|^{\theta p}|f|^{(1-\theta)q}d\mu\\ \leqslant\int_{\Omega}\theta |f|^{p}+(1-\theta)|f|^{q}d\mu=\theta \int_{\Omega}|f|^{p}d\mu+(1-\theta)\int_{\Omega}|f|^{q}d\mu=\theta\|f\|_{L^{p}}^{p}+(1-\theta)\|f\|_{L^{q}}^{q}=\theta \phi(p)+(1-\theta)\phi(q)\,.
$$